# Expression of the sum of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I am unable to calculate the expression of the sum of the series $1^{3/2} + 2^{3/2} + \cdots + n^{3/2}$. Could you please help me finding the answer.

Comment: It is pretty clear that this series diverges, because $\lim_{n\to \infty} n^{3/2} = \infty$. Did you mean to ask for a closed formula for the expression 
$$f(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n k^{3/2}?$$

Comment: @PedroM. Actually, the partial sums are $O(n^{5/2})$.

Comment: @Dr.MV I agree with your statement, but what is your point?

Comment: I haven't tried this, but perhaps you could write the solution as a generic polynomial in $\sqrt n$, like $an^2+bn\sqrt n+cn+d\sqrt n+ e$ and then work out the coefficients from the nonlinear system that results from equating powers of $n$ ?

Comment: @Pedro.M yes I asked for a closed formula..an expression of the sum of that finite series

Answer (score 2):

Notice:

- You can show by the limit test, that this series diverges;
- You can proof it this way:

$$\text{S}=1^{\frac{3}{2}}+2^{\frac{3}{2}}+3^{\frac{3}{2}}+\dots=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{\frac{3}{2}}=\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{m}n^{\frac{3}{2}}=$$
$$\lim_{m\to\infty}\text{H}_m^{\left(-\frac{3}{2}\right)}=\lim_{m\to\infty}-\left(\frac{3\zeta\left(\frac{5}{2}\right)}{16\pi^2}+\zeta\left(-\frac{3}{2},m+1\right)\right)=$$
$$-\frac{3\zeta\left(\frac{5}{2}\right)}{16\pi^2}-\lim_{m\to\infty}\zeta\left(-\frac{3}{2},m+1\right)\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\text{when}\space m\to\infty\space\text{then}\space\text{S}\to\infty$$

- Or using Dirichlet regulariation:

$$\lim_{s\to0}\left[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{\frac{3}{2}-s}\right]=\zeta\left(-\frac{3}{2}\right)=-\frac{3\zeta\left(\frac{5}{2}\right)}{16\pi^2}\approx -0.0254852$$

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^nk^a~$ is known to possess a closed form expression only for $a\in\mathbb N,$ see [Faulhaber's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula#Examples)

for more information. However, we can approximate it by $~\displaystyle\int_1^{n+\tfrac12}x^a~dx~=~\bigg[~\frac{x^{a+1}}{a+1}~\bigg]_1^{n+\tfrac12}$

$=~\dfrac{\Big(n+\tfrac12\Big)^{a+1}-1}{a+1}.$